# I am getting error while trying to select a list for content query web part using query option from tool pane

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

i wish to connect a calender list to CQWP n for that i am trying to select list from tool pane ->Query->Show items from the following list->browse n then there i am getting error as 
[image]

the log viewer shows error as bellow
[image]

Can any body help me??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we activate the "**SharePoint Server Publishing**" feature, "**Images**" library, "**Pages**" library and "**Workflow Tasks**" list will be created in the site.

Please check if there any list or libraries with the same name are existing. If yes, please rename these list or libraries, or move them to another place in SharePoint Designer. Then try to activate the feature again.

If it does not work, please check the ULS log  based on the Correlation id and provide the error message.